# Python Camshift algorithm without opencv

Tags: python, mean-shift

so I have my last assignment and I have to implement **Camshift** algorithm, without using the in built function from opencv library. I have looked everywhere and I cannot find any code, where that would already be solved. Every single person implemented Camshift algorithm with the help of opencv. So if anyone knows how to do it, it would mean the world to me, as it is the assignment that will end my year on college.

Comment: Does this help: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d00/tutorial_meanshift.html?

Comment: Thank you but, I need to implement it without OpenCV